# PyQt5 Variable Creation from For Loop

Tags: for-loop, pyqt5

Instead of doing this:

```
A = (self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'A')).text() # Find the input
B = (self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'B')).text()
C = (self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'C')).text()
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for x in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
   x = (self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, 'x')).text()
```

How do you write more concise code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to store the results in a dictionary:

```
texts = {}
for key in ("A", "B", "C"):
   texts[key] = (self.findChild(QtWidgets.QLineEdit, key)).text()
```

Afterwards you won't be able to use directly `A` but `texts["A"]`.